# Parallelize requests threatment python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-requests

Im building a view (using web2py) with the data of some other websites (about 10) so, for each website i've created a function, it prepares some params, send the request with the params, get the response and do a little treatment, after this the response i passed to the controller and it will build the view with all 10 responses of the request when finished.

My problem is related with speed, because the nature of the HTTP protocol all the requests are sync, and when a server took long time to response, my app keep waiting. I was wonder if there is any way to "parallelize" my function calls so i can do other operations while im waiting the response from another servers.

I've checked grequests and request-futures but i think this doesnt suits very well for this case because i dont just make the request, i do some pre and post processing of the request as i say before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for solutions like `grequest`.

The reason is that most of the time, you wait work I/O operations to complete (downloading the page). It is very likely, that pre and post processing is really marginal comparing to this I/O times.

I have seen really big speedups with `grequest` for web scraping.

In case your pre and postprocessing would also be time consuming, you would have to go for `multiprocessing` module and run the tasks in multiple processes (multiple threads would not help if you would be CPU bound).

But first - really try something like `grequest`.

## HTTP Jobs using grequests

As there is some pre and post processing expected, we have to organize it somehow.

### grequests: concept of "unsent request"

`grequests` has a concept of "unsent request". It is sort of job to be done later on. `grequests`
allows starting these jobs e.g. by `grequests.map` or `grequests.imap`.

### grequests: callback (hooks) on unsent request

Each unsent request can have attached hooks processing returned response.

There can be even more hooks attached to one unsent request.

We will use it for postprocessing.

### Class HttpJobXxx binding things per instance

We want to keep following job-related things somehow organized:

- instantiation: pass in arguments, defining the job to be done
- pre-processing: prepare what is to be prepared
- creation of unsent request
- post-processing of returned response

We will use it later on in these steps:

1. Instantiate the job. This will include call to pre_processing method.
2. Get unsent request by asking job instance to create it. The unsent request will include hook for
   post-processing final response by instance `post_process` call.
3. Add the job instance to list of jobs to do
4. Let the jobs to be run, e.g. by `grequests.map` or `grequests.imap`.

The trick is, that each job instance may take advantage of its own parameters what makes keeping
context information clean during whole job lifecycle.

### HttpJobMyIp

Here is real code:

```
import grequests


class HttpJobMyIp(object):
    url = "https://httpbin.org/ip"

    def __init__(self, nickname="myip over httpbin.org"):
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.pre_process()

    def pre_process(self):
        """Whatever pre-processing you need."""
        print("Preprocessing {self.nickname} with {self.url}".format(self=self))

    @property
    def unsent_request(self):
        """Create requests for grequests.
        Override by whatever construct you need.
        """
        return grequests.get(self.url, hooks={"response": [self.post_process]})

    def post_process(self, response, **kwargs):
        msg = "Post-processing {self.nickname} with {self.url}"
        print(msg.format(self=self))
        assert "origin" in response.json()
        myip = response.json()["origin"]
        print("My IP is {}".format(myip))
```

### HttpJobDelay

To make the example complete, we may add another HTTP job class. This time allowing to call an url,
which responds with some delay.

```
class HttpJobDelay(object):
    url = "https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay}"

    def __init__(self, delay=1, nickname="Delayed response"):
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.delay = delay
        self.pre_process()

    def pre_process(self):
        """Whatever pre-processing you need."""
        msg = ("Preprocessing {self.nickname} "
               "with {self.url} and delay {self.delay}")
        print(msg.format(self=self))
        self.delay = self.delay + 0.7

    @property
    def unsent_request(self):
        """Create requests for grequests.
        Override by whatever construct you need.
        """
        url = self.url.format(delay=self.delay)
        return grequests.get(url, hooks={"response": [self.post_process]})

    def post_process(self, response, **kwargs):
        msg = ("Post-processing {self.nickname} "
               "with {self.url} and expected delay {self.delay}")
        print(msg.format(self=self))
        print("Finally we got (a bit delayed) response")
```

Here we intentionally modify the delay by adding 0.7 seconds to shown, the pre-processing has a
chance to change something.

### Let it all run

```
def exception_handler(request, exception):
    return exception


def main():
    http_jobs = []
    job = HttpJobMyIp("Get my IP")
    http_jobs.append(job.unsent_request)

    for delay in [3, 1, 6, 2]:
        job = HttpJobDelay(delay, "Delay "+str(delay))
        http_jobs.append(job.unsent_request)
    # grequests.map(http_jobs, exception_handler=exception_handler))
    list(grequests.imap(http_jobs, exception_handler=exception_handler), size=6)
    print("DONE")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The plan is to call one instance of `HttpJobMyIp` job and 4 instances of `HttpJobDelay` jobs with
varying requested delays. The delays are intentionally not sorted.

Having all the code above in `mreq.py` file, we can run it:

```
$ python mreq.py                                                                                 1 ↵
Preprocessing Get my IP with https://httpbin.org/ip
Preprocessing Delay 3 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and delay 3
Preprocessing Delay 1 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and delay 1
Preprocessing Delay 6 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and delay 6
Preprocessing Delay 2 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and delay 2
Post-processing Get my IP with https://httpbin.org/ip
My IP is 87.257.712.26
Post-processing Delay 1 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and expected delay 1.7
Finally we got (a bit delayed) response
Post-processing Delay 2 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and expected delay 2.7
Finally we got (a bit delayed) response
Post-processing Delay 3 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and expected delay 3.7
Finally we got (a bit delayed) response
Post-processing Delay 6 with https://httpbin.org/delay/{delay} and expected delay 6.7
Finally we got (a bit delayed) response
DONE
```

## Lessons learned

### Where to find `grequests` documentation

There is no ReadTheDocs documentation.

Instead use:

- source code (whole module has 153 lines incl. comments)
- test suite (235 lines)

Note, that the `HttpJobXxx` class is not a requirement and was created just because I found it handy.

### Callback function arguments: include `**kwargs`

The callback function shall have two parameters:

- `response` (provided by HTTP call)
- `**kwargs`

Without the `**kwargs` the code silently does nothing.

### Silent failures: Use exception handler

Without exception handler in place, if something goes wrong, you will often have no idea, what is
going on. With `exception_handler` you may e.g. get the exception as the result and learn, what went
wrong.

### Too quick quit: `grequests.imap` is generator

Calling `grequests.imap(http_jobs, exception_handler=exception_handler), size=6)` immediately
returns generator and if nothing consumes values from it, it continues and quits.

For this reason is the call encapsulated in `list()`.

### Concurrently processed requests - it works

As we can see, regardless of delays of `HttpJobDelay` instances being not sorted, results are returned
in order - the shortest delay first, the longer last. With `grequests.imap` the
order of unsent requests and of results may differ.

On the other hand with the `grequests.map` the results are returned in the order they were
requested by the list of jobs.

### `grequest.imap` parameter `size` defaults to 2

If you do not specify `size`, it will use default value  of 2. This may affect order of results.

### What speedup to expect

`grequests` run in one process using "green threads". This means, that switching among different
"green threads" is more efficient, as it is done at the moment the code prefers thus saving the
overhead of context swithiching done by CPU and OS.

As the task is I/O limited (most of the time we wait for some data to come), we may live well in
single process.

The highest speedup will be seen with higher number of requests.

Comment: I've readed something about grequests and the few examples i saw allow to make multiple request inside a method, but i've one request per method and in my controllers i call several methods. I mean, my methods have something like: Pre proccess parameters -> Make request -> Request treatment. How can in implement gevent in an architecture like this where each call is fragmented in various methods

Comment: @nastrand Added real code showing, how one can organize pre and post processing into HttpJobXxx class instances.